# Adding a customized section in wordpress menu using wp_customize to select images

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have the following function in my `function.php` file;

```
function customize_images($wp_customize){

$wp_customize->add_section( 'customize_images_save', array(
    'title'    => __('Custom Image', 'themename'),
    'description' => 'Select Image',
    'priority' => 120,
));

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'image_option', array(
        'default'           => 'image.jpg',
        'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
        'type'           => 'option',

    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'image_option', array(
        'label'    => __('Select Image', 'themename'),
        'description' => '',
        'section'  => 'customize_images_save',
        'priority'    => 10,
        'settings' => 'image_option',
    )));
```

}

which is supposed to add a custom section in my WordPress customize menu.

Then the following codes to display the `image in my home-page.php` file;

```
<?php 
    $my_image_top = get_theme_mod( 'image_option', 'default.jpg' );
    $image_top = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $my_image_top , 'full' ); 
?>

<img src="<?php echo $image_top ?>">
```

Unfortunately it's not displaying anything and it's just returning a blank `<img src"">`. I've been struggling to find the error, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, here's the correction in  `$wp_customize->add_setting`.

Here's the setting reference from WordPress Codex;

```
<?php add_settings_field( $id, $title, $callback, $page, $section, $args ); ?>
```

Wrong Argument Old Code;

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'image_option', array(
    'default'           => 'image.jpg',
    'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
    'type'           => 'option',

));
```

I was having the image selector `'type' => 'option'` as an option.

Here's the edited Code which fix this matter:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'image_option', array(
        'default'           => 'image.jpg',
));
```

I hope it help someone in the future. More information about the `$wp_customize->add_setting` Usage here: [WordPress Function Reference/add settings field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field)